# Access InfluxDB 2 through Traefik via subdomain

Tags: docker, influxdb, traefik, influxdb-2

I've installed Traefik and InfluxDB on docker, and am trying to configure Traefik to act as a reverse proxy for all InfluxDB requests via a subdomain e.g. https://influxdb.mydomain.com.

The InfluxDB labels I have are:

```
- traefik.enable=true
- traefik.http.routers.influxdb.entryPoints=websecure
- traefik.http.routers.influxdb.rule=Host(`influxdb.mydomain.com`)
- traefik.http.routers.influxdb.tls=true
- traefik.http.routers.influxdb.tls.certresolver=cloudflare
- traefik.http.services.influxdb.loadbalancer.server.port=8086
```

When accessing InfluxDB, I can see the page loading, but get a `404` on `/api/v2/setup` (when I inspect the network requests), so it doesn't load completely. All other resource load correctly e.g. `/6588f709b0.js`, `/26.c9f12339d6.js`, etc.

I can access InfluxDB via port `8086` without issues `http://influxdb.mydomain.com:8086`.

Any idea what I might be missing to allow access to `/api` via Traefik?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting a solution to my issue in case anyone else runs into a similar problem.

I had setup Traefik to route all `/api` requests to itself, since Traefik also has the `/api` endpoint, without specifying the `Host`.  After specifying the `Host` for the Traefik container, `/api` requests get routed correctly to the `influx` sub-domain.  Traefik Dashboard and InfluxDB are on different sub-domains.

Comment: Can you please post the necessary changes you had to make (to the docker-compose file I suppose)?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Traefik anymore -- moved to Nginx Proxy Manager, so don't have the config anymore.  But from memory, I've created a local DNS record with separate subdomains for each service, which was used to correctly route the traffic.